# using xml in sql server reporting services

Tags: sql-server, xml, reporting-services

could use some help trying to handle xml in sql server reporting services:

we are allowing users to create their own custom forms and accept different input types, including text and radio (simple text responses), checkboxes, lists, and multiselects (multiple text responses), and tables (complex, matrix text responses). the forms have multiple questions and many different types of inputs.

the tabular responses have been a bear since users can create an arbitrary number of columns and rows. i'm storing all this in an xml field. from the .net side of things, i think i'm fine and can display everything nicely in html. i'm now trying to use this data in reporting services and find myself stuck.

how can i display the following data in reporting services so that it may be formatted in a relatively understandable table format? if it would be easier to format my xml differently, i'm more than open to that as well.

the database xml:

```
<answers type="table">
  <rows>
    <row>
      <cell>Answer A</cell>
      <cell>Answer B</cell>
      <cell>Answer C</cell>
      <cell>Answer D</cell>
      <cell>Answer E</cell>
    </row>
    <row>
      <cell>Answer F</cell>
      <cell>Answer G</cell>
      <cell>Answer H</cell>
      <cell>Answer I</cell>
      <cell>Answer J</cell>
    </row>
  </rows>
</answers>
```

as reference, if it helps, an example of the other input types is below (stored in the same xml field):

```
<answers type="multiselect">
  <answer>Option 3</answer>
  <answer>Option 4</answer>
</answers>
```

the desired formatting for the tables(roughly, since there can be any number of columns or rows):

```
Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5
Answer A | Answer B | Answer C | Answer D | Answer E
Answer F | Answer G | Answer H | Answer I | Answer J
```

thank you.